# Exclude from array doesn't work as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack, acts-as-taggable

I'm trying to use `ransack` gem with `acts_as_taggable`. I have a simple `Job` model that configured `acts_as_taggable` in a default way and has `tag_list` property.

When I run:

```
Job.ransack("tags_name_in"=>["eum", "sint"]).result.to_sql
```

It generates SQL as expected (which is good):

```
"SELECT \"jobs\".* FROM \"jobs\" LEFT OUTER JOIN \"taggings\" ON \"taggings\".\"taggable_id\" = \"jobs\".\"id\" AND \"taggings\".\"context\" = 'tags' AND \"taggings\".\"taggable_type\" = 'Job' LEFT OUTER JOIN \"tags\" ON \"tags\".\"id\" = \"taggings\".\"tag_id\" WHERE \"tags\".\"name\" IN ('eum', 'sint')"
```

But when I'm trying to exclude by using:

```
Job.ransack("tags_name_not_in"=>["eum", "sint"]).result.to_sql
```

It throws exaptation:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `left' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::QueryAttribute:0x007f851ea6bcd8>
    from /Users/sashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/ransack-1.8.2/lib/ransack/adapters/active_record/context.rb:190:in `block in build_correlated_subquery'
    from /Users/sashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/ransack-1.8.2/lib/ransack/adapters/active_record/context.rb:189:in `each'
    from /Users/sashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/ransack-1.8.2/lib/ransack/adapters/active_record/context.rb:189:in `build_correlated_subquery'
    from /Users/sashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/ransack-1.8.2/lib/ransack/adapters/active_record/ransack/nodes/condition.rb:9:in `block in arel_predicate'
    from /Users/sashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/ransack-1.8.2/lib/ransack/adapters/active_record/ransack/nodes/condition.rb:6:in `map'
    from /Users/sashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/ransack-1.8.2/lib/ransack/adapters/active_record/ransack/nodes/condition.rb:6:in `arel_predicate'
    from /Users/sashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/ransack-1.8.2/lib/ransack/visitor.rb:17:in `visit_Ransack_Nodes_Condition'
    from /Users/sashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/ransack-1.8.2/lib/ransack/visitor.rb:52:in `visit'
    from /Users/sashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/ransack-1.8.2/lib/ransack/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
    from /Users/sashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/ransack-1.8.2/lib/ransack/adapters/active_record/ransack/visitor.rb:4:in `block in visit_and'
    from /Users/sashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/ransack-1.8.2/lib/ransack/adapters/active_record/ransack/visitor.rb:4:in `map'
    from /Users/sashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/ransack-1.8.2/lib/ransack/adapters/active_record/ransack/visitor.rb:4:in `visit_and'
    from /Users/sashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/ransack-1.8.2/lib/ransack/visitor.rb:24:in `visit_Ransack_Nodes_Grouping'
    from /Users/sashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/ransack-1.8.2/lib/ransack/visitor.rb:52:in `visit'
    from /Users/sashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/ransack-1.8.2/lib/ransack/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
    from /Users/sashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/ransack-1.8.2/lib/ransack/adapters/active_record/context.rb:37:in `evaluate'
... 12 levels...
    from /Users/sashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/sashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
    from /Users/sashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/sashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/sashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
    from /Users/sashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
    from /Users/sashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:191:in `block in serve'
    from /Users/sashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `fork'
    from /Users/sashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `serve'
    from /Users/sashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /Users/sashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /Users/sashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /Users/sashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/sashar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/sashar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas?